# How to get Part-Of-Speech tags w/o fluff

Tags: nlp-compromise

Is there any way to get POS tags without any other chaff?

```
let doc = nlp("I am a librarian at the Yale University, do you know what that is?")
console.log(doc.out("tags"))
```

The above prints POS tags along side named entities and other stuff I'm not interested in. I just want the "all so basic" POS tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this using a map function.  Try this.

```
console.log(doc.out("tags").map(obj => obj.tags))
```